# Randomize letters in a word

Tags: python

the question asks to have to user enter a one word string, then randomize the place of the letters in the word, for example, "hello" can turn into "elhlo"

```
import random

def word_jumble():
    word = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
    new_word = ""
    for ch in range(len(word)):
        r = random.randint(0,len(word)-1)
        new_word += word[r]
        word = word.replace(word[r],"",1)
    print new_word

def main():
    word_jumble()

main()
```

I got the program from someone else, but have no idea how it works. can someone explain to me please? I understand everything before

```
new_word += word[r]
```

Comment: If you want to understand it, try putting print statements eg: `print word[r], new_word` before and after that line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is unnecessarily complex, maybe this will be easier to understand:

```
import random
word = raw_input("Enter a word: ")

charlst = list(word)        # convert the string into a list of characters
random.shuffle(charlst)     # shuffle the list of characters randomly
new_word = ''.join(charlst) # convert the list of characters back into a string
```

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner at python. what does the list() random.shuffle() and join() do?

Comment: If it's a homework assignment, she may not be allowed to use the shuffle method

Comment: @MandyQuan Linking the documentation: [`shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles randomly the elements of a list in place, and [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) concatenates the elements of a list of strings into a single string, using a separator (which is an empty string in this case). My solution is more idiomatic, meaning: it's more in line with the way of doing things in Python

Comment: @MohammadS. you're right, it is for homework, the teacher haven't taught this yet, but there isn't any restrictions to what methods can be used, i think...

OscarLopez - Okay okay everything make sense to me now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`r` is a randomly selected index in the word, so `word[r]` is a randomly selected character in the word.  What the code does is it selects a random character from `word` and appends it to `new_word`  (`new_word += word[r]`).  The next line removes the character from the original word.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `bytearray`, you can use `random.shuffle` directly

```
import random
word = bytearray(raw_input("Enter a word: "))
random.shuffle(word)
```